# How to write a shell script that indents all files C/C++ files in the current directory?

Tags: c, bash, indentation

I am trying to run `indent -kr -i8` on all files in my current directory. Being a C programmer, the idea that came to my mind was to fork processes equal to the number of fles, the run exec on them. But I know things can be simplified with shell scripts. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Please get some quality control involved - you should not need to do this. If one of my charges gave me code that was not indented reasonably I would tell them to come back later when they are done. To me it smacks they have not thought of the code.

Comment: `indent -kr -i8 *.[ch]` should just work according to the current [GNU indent documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html#SEC2) is there more to the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you not just:

```
indent -kr -i8 *.c
```

You mention forking processes, so if you wanted to do it concurrently:

```
for f in *.c
do
   indent -kr -i8 $f &
done
```

But that will trash the cpu if you've got a load of files.  So in batches:

```
limit=10
for f in *.c
do
   indent -kr -i8 $f &
   (( count = count + 1 ))

   if [[ $count -eq $limit ]] then
      wait
      count=0
   fi
done
```

Comment: +1 for building up the answer incrementally... perhaps you could provide a complete script for those unfamiliar with shell programming... :-)

Comment: I missed `count=0` from the `if`, oops.  Now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` for this, in combination with `xargs` and its special arguments specifying the maximum number of processes, and the number of arguments (files) to process for each.

```
find -name '*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 --max-args=1 --max-procs=8 indent -kr -i8
```

Answer (score 0):

launch a process that explicitly calls programs like AStyle or bcpp
[Astyle code formatting tool](http://astyle.sourceforge.net) with GnuParallel

But is it really necessary to fork so much processes for a so simple and fast task?